# Removing 'width' from a css class using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm working on jQuery UI DatePicker. When I'm using `changeMonth` and `changeYear` attributes, both month and year `select` controls are looking weird. I want to have them next to each other with a space

[image]

I dig a little using developer tools and found that it's width is fixed to **49%**

Though I've the css file handy with me, I'm not supposed to change anything part of it.

I tried a couple of workarounds...

I created a class called `widthClass`

```
.widthClass{
   width : '0px !important';
 }
```

added it to the month controller

```
$('.ui-datepicker-month').addClass('widthClass');
```

Second approach is,

```
$('.ui-datepicker-month').css('width', '');
```

but neither of them gives proper result. Help me out...

This is how my controller should look like...

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I'm able to modify the month and year controls width by adding `.click()` handler to the text field. And I'm able to see the desire o/p. But when I click on any other navigation controls in the datepicker, it is getting reset and looking like the older one.

What I did in `.click()` call is..

```
$("<text-field-class>").click(function(){
     $('.ui-datepicker-month, .ui-datepicker-year').css('wdith', '30%');
});
```

How to keep this applied style permanent even if I use next / previous / today controls??

Comment: did you try `.css('width', 'auto');` ?

Comment: And I assume you calling `$('.ui-datepicker-month')` after datepicker was created? Can you verify that given selection returns elements?

Comment: @IliaG Yes. It returns [object Object]

Comment: it is always returns object, but does the object contain elements? You need to check `$('.ui-datepicker-month').size()` to see the number of elements that matched your selector.

Comment: @IliaG It is giving 1 when modified as `$('select.ui-datepicker-month').size()`

Comment: A simpler approach would be overriding it in `CSS` and **not** using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a proper `DOCTYPE` to the page which is being used across my application. That has automatically adjusted the drop downs next to each other. Also, it has solved another issue with the control.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.ui-datepicker-month').css('width', 'auto');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Maverick solution **or**

```
$('.ui-datepicker-month').css('width', '0px !important');
```

Comment: @Sriram So is this a browser issue? Have you verified it in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer and experiment with http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

There is a live demo in the link. Also there is a **Theming** tab to customize your datepicker. Also check your page CSS to check for CSS conflicts.